How to efficiently migrate specific Jenkins jobs/credentials to new server while preserving the original Jenkins environment and handling credentials?
How can I efficiently migrate specific Jenkins jobs, including their configurations and dependencies, to a new Jenkins server using code, while preserving the existing Jenkins environment on the old server?
My main motto, is to create a script in which i can just run required jobs and it gets exported on to the new server with credentials and secrets!
I cant find practices which is efficient for today's time.
I read JCasC and Job DSL plugin , but i am a newbie, i didnt find a fullproof way which i can do using code.
I do not want to use the method of copying the Jenkins root folder to another server.
